# adding validation annotators to model classes when using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, validation, attributes, metadata

How should I add the following attrubute

[Required(ErrorMessage="...")]

to one of the model properties when my model classes are automatically generated.

There is a solution [here](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx), but it seems to be working only on Entity Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same solution can be applied for LINQ to SQL. The snippet the article shows for using the `MetadataType` will use perfectly well with LINQ to SQL generated classes:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetaData))]
public partial class Movie
{
}

public class MovieMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public object Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public object Director { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Date Released")]
    [Required]
    public object DateReleased { get; set; }
}
```